# TypeError: unorderable types: IntVar() > int()

Tags: python, tkinter, int

I'm trying to make a clicker game on python but I keep getting the error `"TypeError: unorderable types: IntVar() > int()"` I have looked at other posts and still don't understand the `.get` thing. here is my code so far:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
import sys

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.geometry("160x100")
root.title("Cliker game")
global counter
counter = tkinter.IntVar()
global multi
multi = 1

def onClick(event=None):
    counter.set(counter.get() + 1*multi)

tkinter.Label(root, textvariable=counter).pack()
tkinter.Button(root, text="I am Cookie! Click meeeeee", command=onClick, 
fg="dark green", bg = "white").pack()


clickable = 0
def button1():
        global multi
        global counter
        if counter > 79:   # this is the line where the error happens
            counter = counter - 80
            multi = multi + 1
            print ("you now have a multiplier of", multi)
        else:
            print ("not enough moneys!")
b = Button(text="+1* per click, 80 cookies", command=button1)
b.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: We'll need, *at the very least*, the full traceback of the exception.

Comment: What happens if you turn the `IntVar` into an `int` like this: `if int(counter) > 79:`

Comment: `counter` is an `IntVar` and you are comparing that with an integer. Perhaps you wanted to use `counter.get() > 79` to get the value stored in the `IntVar` instead?

Comment: Also why are you declaring globals twice?

Comment: @Joe: You can't convert an `IntVar` with `int()`...

Comment: You'll next have issues with `counter = counter - 80`. You need to use `counter.set()` and `counter.get()` there too.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yeah that started to come back to me when I saw your comment with .get()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to compare identical types (or compatible types). In that case, it seems that the `IntVar` object cannot be directly compared to `int`. But it has a `get` method that *returns* an integer.

I'm not a `tk` specialist but this reproduces the issue and provides a fix:

```
>>> root = tkinter.Tk()
>>> counter = tkinter.IntVar()
>>> counter.get()
0
>>> counter < 10
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 301, in runcode
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unorderable types: IntVar() < int()
>>> counter.get() < 10
True
>>>
```

in your case, change:

```
if counter > 79:
```

by

```
if counter.get() > 79:
```

As comments suggested, you have those issues at other places. So use `.get` and `.set` where integers & `IntVar` objects are mixed.

Comment: Your terminology is confusing. Calling `get` on the `IntVar` is not _casting_ it to an integer. "casting" commonly means "converting", and you aren't converting an `IntVar`, you are fetching it's value.

Comment: you're right. Too much C++ lately :=

Comment: Thank you its working now :D