# TypeError: unorderable types: int() < Label()

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

So I am making a quiz as a project for school, which selects already made questions from db browser (SQlite) and displays them using tkinter. When I run the quiz, all graphics appear and then when i enter my answer and submit, this error appears:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1533, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "S:\year 13\computing project\project\MAIN PROJECT CODE.py", line 126, in confirmAnswer
    if self.Qn < self.recordNum:

TypeError: unorderable types: int() < Label()
```

This is just a snippet of the code so if the whole code, just say, thanks for your help!

```
def quiz(self):
            self.newf.pack_forget()
            self.head['text'] = 'Welcome to the psychology revision quiz'
            self.quizf.pack()

            self.quizScore = 0
            self.correctAnswer = ''  # <-- create it at start (and use better name)
            self.Qn = 1
            self.update_question()# <-- get new question
            self.update_question_number()
        def update_question_number(self):
            # Get question's number

            query = "SELECT MAX(qnumber) FROM questions"
            c.execute(query)
            row = c.fetchone()

            self.recordNum['text'] = row[0]

        def update_question(self):
            # Get new question

            query = "SELECT * FROM questions WHERE qnumber=?"
            c.execute(query, (self.Qn,))
            row = c.fetchone()

            self.question['text'] = row[1]

            self.answer1['text'] = row[2]
            self.answer2['text'] = row[3]
            self.answer3['text'] = row[4]
            self.answer4['text'] = row[5]

            self.correctAnswer = row[6]    

        def confirmAnswer(self):
            self.rightOrWrong = self.enterAnswer
            if self.enterAnswer == self.correctAnswer:
                self.rightOrWrong['text'] = "Correct"
                self.quizScore += 1
                self.update_question()
            else:
                self.rightOrWrong['text'] = "Incorrect"

            if self.Qn < self.recordNum:
                self.Qn += 1           # <-- get new question
                self.update_question() # <-- get new question

            else:
                self.rightOrWrong['text'] = "Quiz Complete! Your score was: {}".format(self.quizScore)
```

Comment: Same, same, different: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46426040/797495

Comment: I changed if self.Qn < self.recordNum to if self.Qn < self.recordNum['text']

Comment: And does it work?

Comment: yes it now works and moves onto the next question, however on the line , if self.enterAnswer == self.correctAnswer: self.rightOrWrong['text'] = "correct", it does not display correct or incorrect anywhere and just moves on to the next question

Comment: Good, now you've another problem and  you should create a new question for it. GL.

Comment: I only asked because I have to wait 3 days to ask another question

Comment: We should always be creative!

Comment: Please mark @Rakesh's answer as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try replacing

```
if self.Qn < self.recordNum:
```

with

```
if self.Qn < self.recordNum['text']:
```

Comment: @Pedro Lobito  Thanks

Comment: I was going to, but when I went to, it disappeared, but it’s appeared now, sorry about that @Rakesh